# How to save an object MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to find a solution to my problem on the Internet, but I did not see it. If you know a solution, please tell me.

I am using MongoDB database, and have some schema -

```
const data = await <myCollection>.findOne({<parament>})
// data return some this ->
{
    text: "Some Text",
    object: {
        text: "Text in object"
    }
}
```

And I want to update the object in data. I try use this (in this way i update normal rows)

```
data.object.text = "Epic text"
data.save()
```

But this doesn`t work. Okay, I try and this -

```
const newObject = 
{
    text: "Epic text"
}
<myCollection>.updateOne({<parametr>}, {$set {object: newObject}})
```

But that doesn't work either, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find example how to perform `CRUD operation` in [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-vscode/crud-ops/)

by default, MongoDB provide field `_id` with type `ObjectId` and as `Index` in the document automatically

to update document, you will need the field `_id` (but not limited to use other fields) where you can find it in database or perform query `find()`.

in your case, it should be work if you replace `<paramater>` with the `object` instead.

Noted: you shouldn't do that if the condition key(s) is not an `Index` to avoid `duplicate entry`.

```
const where = { text: "Epic text" }
const newObject = 
{
    text: "Epic text"
}
<myCollection>.updateOne(where, { $set { object: newObject } })
```

we can also use query `update`

```
const where = { text: "Epic text" }
const newObject = 
{
    text: "Epic text"
}
<myCollection>.update(where, { $set { object: newObject } })
```

try it on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8wI-le3BjL5)

Comment: Sorry if you didn't understand me. But I would like not to add a line, change the line in `object`.  For example, I want to replace an old object with a new one

Comment: yeah, it does. you can try it on the link. you can replace `newObject `with any field